# DialogFragment custom view no background

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to inflate a custom view in a `DialogFragment` but the container view's are not showing up. Note I haven't found any post that matches this exactly, so if there is, please share, TIA.
here is my XML (very simple)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/billnotifselectiondialog"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="45dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:background="@color/secondary_200"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

My Class:

```
class BillNotifSelectionDialog:  DialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: TestDialogLayoutBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = TestDialogLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context),container, false).apply {
        binding = this
    }.root
}
```

I'm invoking the class in my fragment with

```
BillNotifSelectionDialog().show(parentFragmentManager, "tag")
```

Here is the result, I can only see the button, not the `ConstraintLayout`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue of using `ConstraintLayout` as the root layout of `DialogFragment`s.

One fix is to Replace it with `RelativeLayout`; but it's not recommended as per [documentation quote](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/relative):

> For better performance and tooling support, you should instead build your layout with ConstraintLayout.

Instead of that you'd fix it programmatically by designating the dialog layout to match the parent with `dialog.window.setLayout`:

```
class BillNotifSelectionDialog : DialogFragment() {
   //..... rest of code omitted

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        dialog!!.window!!.setLayout(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
    }

}
```

Comment: OMGosh, thank you so much, override onStart worked, woo hoo.  Thank you @Zain

Answer (score 0):

you need to override [onCreateDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#onCreateDialog(android.os.Bundle)) instead of onCreateView in DialogFragment.

```
class BillNotifSelectionDialog : DialogFragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: TestDialogLayoutBinding

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        binding = TestDialogLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        return AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setView(binding.root)
            .create()
}
```

to test the result, I changed your xml code that the background color is teal_200 and button color is purple_700

[the code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhSkt.png)